# from google.cloud import speech ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-speech-api

I want to create a telegram bot to convert audio to text format and store it in google cloud storage, for that I've imported google coud libraries
If you could see, other libraries are imported successfully and with no error, unless google-cloud-speech/-storage
When I run the script, it returns error message like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Documents/python projects/s2t/bot.py", line 9, in 
<module>
    from google.cloud import speech_v1
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from google.cloud.speech_v1.gapic import speech_client
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\cloud\speech_v1\gapic\speech_client.py", line 24, in 
<module>
    import google.api_core.gapic_v1.client_info
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from google.api_core.gapic_v1 import config
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\config.py", line 27, in <module>
    from google.api_core import retry
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 67, in <module>
    from google.api_core import datetime_helpers
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\api_core\datetime_helpers.py", line 23, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import timestamp_pb2
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\protobuf\timestamp_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
    from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\python projects\s2t\lib\site- 
packages\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
    from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
ImportError: DLL load failed: Не найдена указанная процедура.


Here is my code:

from __future__ import unicode_literals
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext.dispatcher import run_async
from telegram import ChatAction
from tinytag import TinyTag
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud import storage

from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types
import os
import io

TOKEN = '1048019183:AAFebrbxYt1kz_73M7uSvhL5SC1AOG6NCnk'
PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5002'))
BUCKET_NAME = 'botkvartal'
ADMIN_CHAT_ID = 123456
updater = Updater(TOKEN)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def start(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Пожалуйста, 
воспользуйтесь аудио обращением к нашему боту")


def voice_to_text(bot, update):
    chat_id = update.message.chat.id
    file_name = str(chat_id) + '_' + str(update.message.from_user.id) + 
str(update.message.message_id) + '.ogg'

    update.message.voice.get_file().download(file_name)
    tag = TinyTag.get(file_name)
    length = tag.duration

    speech_client = speech.SpeechClient()

    to_gs = length > 58

    if to_gs:
        storage_client = storage.Client()

        bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
        blob = bucket.blob(file_name)
        blob.upload_from_filename(file_name)
        audio = types.RecognitionAudio(uri='gs://' + BUCKET_NAME + '/' + 
file_name)
    else:
        with io.open(file_name, 'rb') as audio_file:
            content = audio_file.read()
            audio = types.RecognitionAudio(content=content)

    config = types.RecognitionConfig(
        encoding=enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.OGG_OPUS,
        sample_rate_hertz=tag.samplerate,
        language_code='ru-RU')

    bot.send_chat_action(chat_id=chat_id, action=ChatAction.TYPING)
    response = speech_client.long_running_recognize(config, 
audio).result(timeout=500) \
        if to_gs else \
        speech_client.recognize(config, audio)

    message_text = ''
    for result in response.results:
        message_text += result.alternatives[0].transcript + '\n'

    update.message.reply_text(message_text)
    os.remove(file_name)


def ping_me(bot, update, error):
    if not error.message == 'Timed out':
        bot.send_message(chat_id=ADMIN_CHAT_ID, text=error.message)


start_handler = CommandHandler(str('start'), start)
oh_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.voice, voice_to_text)
dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)
dispatcher.add_handler(oh_handler)
dispatcher.add_error_handler(ping_me)
updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

This code is open source and I found it in github, however I want to add some features in it after troubleshooting import errors of google cloud libraries

Comment: Can you try pip install protobuf==3.6.0? [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/25072), [emddudley comment](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046)

Comment: @marian.vladoi, Thank you!

Comment: it worked for you?

Comment: @marian.vladoi, absolutely. I am pretty shocked too xD

Comment: ok I will make it as an answer and please up-vote for better visibility for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You should try downgrading protobuf to 3.6.0.

```
install protobuf==3.6.0
```

or check [emddudley comment](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5046):

> With protobuf-3.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl and Python 2.7.10 (64-bit) on
>   Windows 7 the Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\pyext_message.pyd
>   file does not exist.
>
> With protobuf-3.6.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl and Python 3.6.1 (64-bit)
>   on Windows 7 this file does exist:
>
> Lib\site-packages\google\protobuf\pyext_message.cp36-win_amd64.pyd
>
> When I run from google.protobuf.pyext import _message in the above
>   Python 3 environment it succeeds without errors.